# ServiceStack Open API - Swagger UI not displaying enum values as dropdown

Tags: servicestack

I have recently upgraded my ServiceStack libraries from 5.10.4 to 6.5.0 and implemented Open API as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.servicestack.net/openapi). But my Enum properties are displayed as Textbox instead of Dropdown in the /swagger-ui page.

This was working as expected previously when I was using 'ServiceStack.Api.Swagger' instead of 'ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi'.

Can someone please help me in this?

Thanks and Regards,
Sibin

Below are the code I am using:

```
// Configuration
Plugins.Add(new OpenApiFeature());


// DTO
[Route("my-route", "GET", Summary = "My summary")]
    public class MyClass: IReturn<MyResponse>
    {
        [ApiMember(Name = "Alphabet", Description = "Alphabet",
        ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
        [ApiAllowableValues("Alphabet", typeof(Alphabets))]
        public string Alphabet { get; set; }
    }

// Enum
public enum Alphabets
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should now be resolved in the latest v6.5.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Alternatively you can change your DTO to have an Enum property, which also doesn't require an `[ApiAllowableValues]` attribute, e.g:

```cs
[Route("/my-route", "GET", Summary = "My summary")]
public class MyClass: IReturn<MyResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Alphabet", Description = "Alphabet",
        ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public Alphabets Alphabet { get; set; }
}
```

If you haven't already, checkout [API Explorer](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-explorer) that's built into ServiceStack v6+ which you can view from `/ui` or a specific API from `/ui/{RequestDto}` e.g. `/ui/MyClass`.